# c# convert a part of a json string to objects

Tags: c#, json, decode

ive got a problem decoding a json output from api.openkvk.nl. I only want the ROWS converted to objects, Whats the best way to convert the json rows to a List?

a json example is:

> [{"RESULT":{"TYPES":["bigint","varchar","int","int","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","varchar","bigint","varchar","double","double","date"],"HEADER":["kvk","bedrijfsnaam","kvks","sub","adres","postcode","plaats","type","status","website","vestiging","rechtsvorm","lat_rad","lon_rad","anbi"],"**ROWS**":[["170401310000","Kuijpers Installaties Helmond B.V.","17040131",null,"Panovenweg 18","5708HR","Helmond","Hoofdvestiging",null,null,"16667549",null,"0.89838484100000005","0.098222471000000006",null],["170401310001","KUIJPERS INSTALLATIES B.V.","17040131",null,"VELDZIGT 18","3454PW","DE MEERN","Nevenvestiging","Vestiging is uitgeschreven uit het handelsregister",null,"0",null,null,null,null],["170401310002","Kuijpers Installaties Helmond B.V.","17040131",null,"Heieinde 12","5047SX","Tilburg","Nevenvestiging",null,null,"21790299",null,"0.90039840900000001","0.087662925000000003",null]]}}]

object:

```
public class KvK
    {
        public Int64? kvk { get; set; }
        public string bedrijfsnaam { get; set; }
        public int? kvks { get; set; }
        public int? sub { get; set; }
        public string adres { get; set; }
        public string postcode { get; set; }
        public string plaats { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string website { get; set; }
        public int? vestiging { get; set; }
        public string rechtsvorm { get; set; }
        public decimal? lat_rad { get; set; }
        public decimal? lon_rad { get; set; }
        public DateTime? anbi { get; set; }
    }
```

the idea was to use JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize<> but i could not get it working..

Comment: I would say, parse json and then loop through the collection of items to extract the values you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ROOT>>(json);


public class RESULT
{
    public List<string> TYPES { get; set; }
    public List<string> HEADER { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> ROWS { get; set; }
}

public class ROOT
{
    public RESULT RESULT { get; set; }
}
```